# Postgres: FATAL: number of requested standby connections exceeds max_wal_senders (currently 0)

Tags: postgresql

I setup master-replication and in my slave server logs, I am seeing this error over and over (it repeats every second):

***FATAL: number of requested standby connections exceeds max_wal_senders (currently 0)***

I am able to connect to the slave server, and perform read queries on it and replication seems to be working fine. `max_wal_senders` is set to `3` in the `master` server, and isn't set at all in the slave server, so I'm not sure what the issue is. `max_connections` is set to `1000` in the `slave` server, which is more than enough.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Do you see the same error appearing in the logs on the master side, too?  And can you set the parameter to 3 on the slave side, too?  (Changing it requires a restart.)

Comment: Did you restart the master?

Answer (score 0):

On the master server:

In your PostgreSQL configuration file (postgresql.conf), make sure the following settings are configured to enable replication:

makefile
Copy code
wal_level = replica  # Set the WAL level to 'replica' to enable logical replication
max_wal_senders = 3  # Set the maximum number of concurrent connections that can be used for replication (adjust as needed)
After making these changes, restart the PostgreSQL server for the changes to take effect.

On the standby server (slave):

In your PostgreSQL configuration file (postgresql.conf), make sure the following settings are configured:

```
hot_standby = on  # Enable hot standby mode to allow the server to act as a standby
```

Optionally, you can set the following parameter to specify the number of standby connections to the master:

```
max_standby_streaming_delay = -1  # This parameter controls the maximum delay before canceling queries on the standby
```

Note: max_standby_streaming_delay is optional, and you may not need to set it unless you have specific requirements.

Restart the PostgreSQL server on the standby server after making these changes.

Verify replication status:

After both the master and standby servers have been configured, you should monitor the PostgreSQL logs on both servers to ensure that replication is working without any errors.

On the standby server, you can use the following command to check the replication status:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_replication;
```

This query will show you information about the connected replication clients. If everything is set up correctly, you should see a row representing the master server.